# How to view the HTML source of an email in the Windows 10 Mail app?

Tags: windows-10-mail-app

Pressing the actions button (3 dots) doesn't list anything to view the source. Right clicking only lists "copy" and even when writing a email I can't seem to find a way to view the source.

**How to view the HTML source of an email in the Windows 10 Mail app?**

Answer (score 4):

The only apparent way to do it in the current version of Windows Mail in Windows 10 is to go to **...** > **Save as**, save the file, and then open it in your text editor of choice.